# Node label positioning in CircuitTikz

Tags: circuitikz

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) node[npn](npn) at (0,0) {2N3904};
            \draw (npn.C)
                to [R,l_=560<\ohm>]  (0,3)
                to [short] (0,4);
            \draw (npn.E) --++(0,-0.5) node[ground]{};
            \draw (npn.B) 
                to [short] (-2,0)
                to [R,l^=200<\kilo\ohm>] (-2,3.75)
                to [short] (0,3.75)
                to node[vcc]{+15\,\textnormal{V}} (0,4.5);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

This is the output it produces:

[image: Output]

Is there anyway to move the NPN transistor label "2N3904" down as in the following picture?

[image: Desired Result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
\node[npn, label=right:2N3904](npn) at (0,0) {};
```

instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
            \node[npn, label=right:2N3904](npn) at (0,0) {};
            \draw (npn.C)
                to [R,l_=560<\ohm>] (0,3)
                to [short] (0,4);
            \draw (npn.E) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[ground]{};
            \draw (npn.B) 
                to [short] (-2,0)
                to [R,l^=200<\kilo\ohm>] (-2,3.75)
                to [short] (0,3.75)
                to node[vcc]{+15\,\textnormal{V}} (0,4.5);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```